# Push notification on firebase database changed

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have specific question, I hope it is possible to make such thing.

**CLIENT SIDE**

**First tab - Data**

An app made in React Native with Flat table. Data are located on Firebase database. Data are objects (name, image, price, category and so on). Everything works fine.

**Second tab - Notifications**

Table with categories and checkmarks. The user wants to receive *notifications only for particular categories*, ie beverages, dairy and personal care.

**SERVER SIDE**

Data are updated (mostly added new items) once a day.

**Questions:**

1. How to setup on client side to receive notifications only for specific categories?
2. How to trigger notifications to the users when added new items with categories users registered for? ie "We got new items from Dairy category"

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing matches best with FCM topics. When using topics, each client decides what topic(s) it subscribes to, and your server-side code sends messages to topics. Behind the scenes Firebase then figures out what devices the message needs to be sent to, a process known as topic fan-out.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [sending messages to topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics) and on [subscribing to topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging).

Native clients (iOS, Android) can subscribe directly to topics from the client-side code. Unfortunately, this isn't possible for JavaScript/web clients, for which you'll have to use server-side code to set up the topic subscription (as shown in the second link above). If you're using `react-native-firebase` however, you can use the client-side [`subscribeToTopic` method](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging#subscribeToTopic) as this library wraps the native SDKs.